# Partial String vlookup using str.contains

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do a partial string match merge/vlookup between two datasets using a solution I modified for my dataset

```
def partial(x):
    return new_file.loc[new_file['name'].str.contains(x),'global_id'].iloc[0]
df2['new'] = df2['name'].apply(partial)
```

The idea is to get the global id from new file in cases where the name contains a string similar to the one in df2

Here is an example of what df2 looks like

```
name 
Joe George Harris
Freddy *$&# Luis *&# Francis
```

and newfile:

```
name              global_id
Joe Harris               2
Freedy Francis          50
```

These are not exact replicas of my dataset, but kind of resembles my data (just a lot more data)

Running my code returns this error message:

```
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

I assume I might be getting this error because some of the values in newfile['name'] do not exist in the first dataframe, but not sure how to address this assuming this is the problem

Comment: it sounds like you want to do a join of two tables based on a matching column `'name'`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html

Comment: Can you share more of your code, and some data? As @julian said, you might be looking for a merge. If it turns out that isn’t the case, there is probably still a better solution.